# how to avoid getting system.data.datarowview in a combobox after making the dataset bound to the combobox null in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, dataset

I have a combo box in my C# code which takes value from a database. The database data first bound to a dataset and then set to the combo box. I want to clear the combo box after a button click and get data again when another button has been clicked.

```
cbVmUserName.DataSource = ds_4.Tables["VmUserNames"];
cbVmUserName.ValueMember = "vm_username";
cbVmUserName.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

This is how I bind the data to combo box using a dataset called ds_4.
Then I tried to clear the combo box data using the following code line.
    cbVmUserName.DataSource = null;
But when I'm trying to get data again what I get is system.data.datarowview as combo box items.
How to solve this problem and get real data again ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the display member setting to say what values are actually displayed.

```
 cbVmUserName.DisplayMember = "DisplayValue";
```

You can also use the below to remove all items from the combo box.

```
 cbVmUserName.Items.Clear();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I got the same problem eve.n after using this method. Later I solved it by making the dataset null.
ex: ds_4=null;
After setting it null we can clear items without any problem.